Exporting the Test Version with Xray Enterprise using Doc Generator
We have just upgraded to Xray Enterprise and are starting to use Test Versions.
However, we cannot find a way to 'export' the Test Version (Name) in our 'Doc. Generator' exports (we're using the standard templates examples pretty much, a for Test Plan).
Does anyone know how we might access this value? I can see from the API it appears under the 'TestRun' using /api/testrun?testExecIssueKey=XXX&testIssueKey=XXX, but need the template code to access it if possible..?
Running Xray Enterprise v1.0.1 Data Center
